# Typical Win32 file drop (IDropTarget::Drop) implementation?

Tags: c++, winapi, drag-and-drop

I am trying to make a Windows Explorer-like program in C++ without MFC.

It has a list view which shows the file system directories and files.

I want to add the drop target functionality for the list view,

so I implemented IDropTarget interface and registered the hwnd.

With IDropTargetHelper, I simply achieved the desired drag&drop effect
in DragEnter, DragOver, DragLeave method.

But in Drop method, the dropTargetHelper was helpless.

My list view only accepts File drops.

Should I implement the dropped files' COPY, MOVE, LINK operation for myself?

OR is there a simple shell file operation helper which accepts dropped IDataObject?

---

EDIT:

I know how to get filenames from the dropped object, and just file copying is easy.

But I think maybe there are more things to consider: for example, making a file link, source item is virtual, and so on.

So I wonder if there are helper methods available from Windows shell.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/explorerdragdrop.aspx http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/filedroplistctrl.aspx http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide1.aspx

Comment: This also is a good and minimal simple sample using a C++ class without MFC and working even for Win 2000: http://www.catch22.net/tuts/dragdrop/6

Comment: @user - Yes, I don't remember what my comment was about. Deleted it.

Comment: The first document of the top comment implemented drag-and-drop using MFC. The person specifically asked "without MFC". I need a C++ code that initiates file drag-and-drop to File Explorer using pure Windows API, without using MFC.

Answer (score 2):

The textbook example would be the one from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940354.aspx). Do read [Old New Thing articles 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/03/10006065.aspx) and [2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/28/10016692.aspx).