# Application using different mechanism of WM_DROPFILES for drag and drop

Tags: windows

Trying to automatize drag and drop from my app (app 1) to a third party app (app 2) on windows.

App 2 recognizes dragging and dropping files on its window from explorer (the files are added to a list) but, after unsuccesful tryes by my side with app 1 (using WN_DROPFILES, ecc), I used spy++ to examine all the messages on app 2 when i drag and drop files on it.

As there is no WM_DROPFILES messages in all the messages captured by spy++, app 2 clearly uses a different mechanism.

I'm on windows 10, tried launching app 2 both as user as administrator (and strangely when I run as administrator a popup appear saying that Drag and drop will not work, but in reality it does).

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: The other mechanism is `IDropTarget` https://stackoverflow.com/q/6148055/103167 which was designed to allow drag/drop from sources other than the shell and of items other than files.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it

Comment: Well, tried the IDropTarget route: If i drag and drop files from my app to an explorer window, the files are copied; if I do the same dragging the files to app 2, a deny sign appears.

Comment: Are your app and app 2 both running at the same integrity level (both elevated or neither are?)

Comment: Yes they are. I think app 2 has been specifically developed with the intention of forbidding drag and drop in the known methods. I'm using autoit to physically move the mouse, click on the various controls on the app, ecc. Apparently it works

Comment: If it were designed for drag-and-drop not to work, you couldn't drag from explorer.